# To create a site to manage reservations and payments for houses in the different days of the year

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I want to create a site to manage reservations and payments for houses in the different days of the year. Are there CMSs or services that I can add or implement on my site?
I would like to create a site similar to Airbnb but obviously much simpler.
Do you know the name of any plugins that I can use with Drupal or Wordpress?
If there are no free services, which paid software do you recommend?
See you soon and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For customers book reservations, appointments or rentals

you can use the following setup.

Word press with "WooCommerce Bookings"(not the eCommerce plugin) or Booking calendar, Appointment Booking System By WpDevArt, Or WP Booking System By Veribo, Roland Murg.

With Joomla check following

https://extensions.joomla.org/category/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations/

for drupal use drupalcommerce or ubercart.